Excel macro "Design Mode" not working
When I click on the buttons while "Design Mode" is selected, shouldn't the macro not run and go to design mode (where the code is)?
When I click the button while design mode is not active;

When I click the button while design mode is active;

I add any ActiveX control element to my page. I cannot switch to "Design Mode" while "Design Mode" is selected in the menu above. In other words; I cannot open the ActiveX element I added in "Design Mode". The ActiveX element is run immediately.
Can you help? Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What kind of button did you use? When you insert them you have two options: upper section, sheet control elements; or bottom section, ActiveX control elements (might be different translation); I can replicate your error using the upper section.

you're right, in design mode you should be able to right click controls and view code behind them or see their properties. Seems like a bug / corrupted installation / temporary issue. Unfortunately there is no definite solution for this kind of issues, order of trials I'd attempt: restart Excel; reboot pc; reinstall Office
